# Error in SQL Syntax. What would be the proper solution or right syntax to use for a successful result?

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp

MySQL said:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '(14) NOT NULL ) ENGINE=MyISAM' at line 23

```
CREATE TABLE  `activity_points` (
 `fk_user_id` INT( 10 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0',
 `date` DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0000-00-00',
 `points` INT( 10 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0',
 `lastupdate` TIMESTAMP( 14 ) NOT NULL
) ENGINE = MYISAM ;
```

Comment: `TIMESTAMP` does not accept length. It should only be `TIMESTAMP` alone. eg `lastupdate TIMESTAMP`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TIMESTAMP shouldn't have length

```
CREATE TABLE  `activity_points` (
 `fk_user_id` INT( 10 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0',
 `date` DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0000-00-00',
 `points` INT( 10 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0',
 `lastupdate` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
) ENGINE = MYISAM ;
```